# I am trying to open custom chrome tab from nested recycler view but couldn't having error Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

Here is the code I am using to open the custom chrome tab

```
val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context.applicationContext, Uri.parse("https://www.codingkaro.in"))
```

This is set on a button click listener inside nested recycler view. I have passed the `context` from the MainActivity as `this@MainActivity`

This is the error I am getting

```
Process: com.shyptsolution.classproject, PID: 31505
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier I didn't know how to `addFlags()` to this but now the code looks like this

```
val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
                customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(holder.download.rootView.context, Uri.parse("https://www.codingkaro.in"))
```

and everything works fine.
I just added
`customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`